# Control Python verbosity / log handler level in travis to mitigate errors due to exceeding log file size

Tags: python, logging, travis-ci

When I run my unit tests locally, they generate a logfile of about 400 KB.  However, when they are [run on travis](https://travis-ci.com/pytroll/fogpy/branches), there is apparently some really verbose log handler active, as the tests [error due to the logfile exceeding 4 MB](https://travis-ci.com/pytroll/fogpy/jobs/209272803).  How can I control the output verbosity of the travis test runs?

I've also tried to use pytest to run the tests (which are in pyunit), as pytest captures the output.  This results in my tests [erroring due to a lack of output for ten minutes](https://travis-ci.com/pytroll/fogpy/jobs/209217389).

In case it matter, I am using the [ci-helpers](https://github.com/astropy/ci-helpers) package.

Comment: There are so many logs like: `[INFO: 2019-06-19 12:36:24 : lowwatercloud] Cloud base <902.8996580174423> is higher than cloud top <800.0>. Autmatically reduced to <799.0>`. As they are `info` level, they should also be generated on your local machine. Strange?

Comment: @Sraw They are only generated on my local machine if I define a handler with level INFO or above.  When I run my unit tests, I set my handler to level WARNING (through an environment variable).  The format with the square brackets is not something defined locally, travis seems to log all, including DEBUG...

Comment: @Sraw So although I agree that most of those INFO levels should be DEBUG instead, it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: OK, so if you can control the level by an environment variable, why don't you set that variable in `.travis.yml`? BTW, how about trying to control level in your program, just for testing. Like `logger.setLevel(50)` to disable all logs.

Comment: @Sraw I can and do use an environment variable for the logging handler that I define in my code; but it appears that travis defines its own and I don't know how to control that.  But I will try if I can override it with your `logger.setLevel(50)` advice.

Comment: @Sraw That does shut up the logfiles, such that I'm back to [erroring due to a lack of output for ten minutes](https://travis-ci.com/pytroll/fogpy/jobs/209329615) :) — but it's not a desirable solution anyway...